# ExtJS - Grid Cell Tool Tip

Tags: extjs, grid, tooltip, cell, onmouseover

I am trying to create a tooltip for cells. Below code does that, but tooltip appears only onClick(in mozilla) and in IE tooltip appears on mouseOver but display value of last clicked cell.

I wanted a tooltip on grid in mouseOver with cells content as tooltip display value.

Please suggest any other way to achieve that. Thanks in advance.

```
var grid = Ext.getCmp('your_grid_id');   // Enter your grid id
initToolTip(grid); // call function

initToolTip: function(grid) {
var view = grid.view;

// record the current cellIndex
grid.mon(view, {
    uievent: function(type, view, cell, recordIndex, cellIndex, e) {
        grid.cellIndex = cellIndex;
        grid.recordIndex = recordIndex;
    }
});

grid.tip = Ext.create('Ext.tip.ToolTip', {
    target: view.el,
    delegate: '.x-grid-cell',
    trackMouse: true,
    renderTo: Ext.getBody(),
    listeners: {
        beforeshow: function updateTipBody(tip) {
            if (!Ext.isEmpty(grid.cellIndex) && grid.cellIndex !== -1) {
                header = grid.headerCt.getGridColumns()[grid.cellIndex];
                columnText = grid.getStore().getAt(grid.recordIndex).get(header.dataIndex);

                tip.update(columnText);
            }
        }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use [`renderer`](https://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.6/#!/api/Ext.grid.column.Column-cfg-renderer) config for [`gridcolumn`](https://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.6/#!/api/Ext.grid.column.Column) and inside of `renderer` you could return a html tag with you `data-qtip` based on your record what you need to show.

You can check here with working [Fiddle](https://fiddle.sencha.com/fiddle/2md8).

Code:

```
Ext.application({
    name: 'Fiddle',

    launch: function () {
        Ext.create('Ext.data.Store', {

            storeId: 'simpsonsStore',

            fields: ['name', 'email', 'phone'],
            data: [{
                'name': 'Lisa',
                "email": "lisa@simpsons.com",
                "phone": "555-111-1224"
            }, {
                'name': 'Bart',
                "email": "bart@simpsons.com",
                "phone": "555-222-1234"
            }, {
                'name': 'Homer',
                "email": "homer@simpsons.com",
                "phone": "555-222-1244"
            }, {
                'name': 'Marge',
                "email": "marge@simpsons.com",
                "phone": "555-222-1254"
            }]
        });

        Ext.create('Ext.grid.Panel', {

            title: 'Simpsons',

            store: 'simpsonsStore',

            columns: [{
                text: 'Name',
                dataIndex: 'name',
                renderer: function (value, metaData, record, rowIndex, colIndex, store) {
                    return `<span data-qtip="This is ${value}"> ${value} </span>`;
                }
            }, {
                text: 'Email',
                dataIndex: 'email',
                flex: 1
            }, {
                text: 'Phone',
                dataIndex: 'phone'
            }],

            height: 200,

            renderTo: Ext.getBody()
        });
    }
});
```